# Shiny app with an adaptive data frame for change point analysis

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build an app which lets you generate data points from multiple distributions and run a change-point analysis on the generated data.
The idea is:

1. Select the desired distribution
2. Input parameters for the desired distribution
3. With a press of a button append the generated data to the main data frame
4. When the button is pressed, automatically run the change-point analysis and output a plot of the data with vertical lines, showing the change-points and also output the summary of the fit

## app code

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Latvian")

#changepoint detection packages
library(changepoint)

#misc packages
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Changepoint detection using R packages"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Generate data",
                 selectInput("distribution", "Distribution", choices = c("Normal", "Uniform")),
                 uiOutput("ui_selected"),
                 actionButton("button_click", "Add")
                 )
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotly::plotlyOutput("cpts"),
      verbatimTextOutput("summary")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$ui_selected <- renderUI({
    
    if (input$distribution == 'Normal'){
      list(numericInput("mean", "Mean", 0),
      numericInput("sd", "Standard deviation", 1),
      numericInput("length", "Length", 30),
      numericInput("seed", "Seed", 123))
    } else if (input$distribution == 'Uniform'){
      list(numericInput("minimum", "Min value", 0),
      numericInput("maximum", "Max value", 1),
      numericInput("length", "Length", 30),
      numericInput("seed", "Seed", 123))
    }
  })
  
  data <- data.frame(x = numeric(0), y = numeric(0))
  
  observeEvent(input$button_click,{
    if (input$distribution == 'Normal'){
      set.seed(input$seed)
      a <- rnorm(input$length, input$mean, input$sd)
      b <- data.frame(x = seq(length(data$x)+1, length(a)), y = a)
      data <- rbind.data.frame(data, b)
    }
    if (input$distribution == 'Uniform'){
      set.seed(input$seed)
      a <- runif(input$length, input$min, input$max)
      b <- data.frame(x = seq(length(data$x)+1, length(a)), y = a)
      data <- rbind.data.frame(data, b)
    }
  })
  
  
  rval_changepoint_fit <- eventReactive(input$button_click,{
    changepoint_fit <- cpt.mean(data$y, method = "PELT")
    changepoint_fit
  })
  
  output$cpts <- plotly::renderPlotly({
    ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y))+
      geom_line()+
      geom_vline(xintercept = cpts(rval_changepoint_fit()), col = "red")})
  
  output$summary <- renderPrint({rval_changepoint_fit()})
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have tested the app with a preset data set and it seemed to work, however, when I implemented the ability to generate data, it gives me an error:

```
Warning: Error in multiple.mean.norm: Minimum segment legnth is too large to include a change in this data
  [No stack trace available]
Warning: Error in multiple.mean.norm: Minimum segment legnth is too large to include a change in this data
  [No stack trace available]
```

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Where do you define the input `main_selector`? If you look at the traceback from the error, you'll see that `input$main_selector == 'Normal'` is at fault. If you debug it (e.g., `browser()` in that `observeEvent`), you'll see that `input$main_selector` is `NULL` and therefore the `if` conditional is `logical(0)`.

Comment: thank you, I have updated the question since a different error still persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up front:

- you use `data.frame$x` (twice), it should be `data$x`;
- you also have a sequencing problem, perhaps use `x = nrow(data) + seq(input$length)`; and
- for both of those, I find using `data` to be occasionally confused with the `utils::data` function, consider using a name that isn't the same as a common base-R function

---

Let me explain how I troubleshot this. This is by far not the only mechanism, but it works well in my dev environment.

One step would be to insert `browser()` into every (likely) reactive block and trace it line-by-line (on the console, this does not work with shinyapps.io or any other shiny "server" of sorts). However, with larger apps, this can be onerous, slow, and frankly it might not find an error on the first (or tenth) pass through a block. (And you might forget to remove  all instances of `browser()` ...)

Because of this, it can be extremely helpful to know which line is causing the error. To do this, R can provide a stack track (via `traceback()`), but when running within shiny this can be difficult to get when you need it (and it is transient). One technique to get immediate line-number hints (when possible) is with this:

```r
options(
  error = function() {
    sink(stderr())
    on.exit(sink(NULL))
    traceback(3, max.lines = 1L)
    if (!interactive()) {
      q(status = 1)
    }
  }
)

(function() { 1                  # line 1
   2                             # line 2
   3                             # line 3
   stop("quux")                  # line 4
 })()                            # line 5
# Error in (function() { : quux
# 2: stop("quux") at #4                     <---- line 4 of my anonymous function
# 1: (function() {
#     ...
```

So let's apply that to your app. I saved your app to a `.R` file, and so the line numbers might not perfectly align with yours, but the steps will still carry over.

```r
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

# [1] "LC_COLLATE=Latvian_Latvia.1257;LC_CTYPE=Latvian_Latvia.1257;LC_MONETARY=Latvian_Latvia.1257;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Latvian_Latvia.1257"
# Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3877
# Warning: Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
#   79: seq
#   77: observeEventHandler [~/StackOverflow/11362744/61855868.R#55]
#    6: runApp
#    4: print.shiny.appobj
#    2: ss
#    1: .ess.source
```

(There's one hint: when R complains about `'closure' is not subsettable`, it means that you think something is *data* (and try to subset it with `$` or `[`) when it is in fact a `function`.)

Looking at lines 53-57, we have

```r
      set.seed(input$seed)
      a <- rnorm(input$length, input$mean, input$sd)
      b <- data.frame(x = seq(length(data.frame$x)+1, length(a)), y = a)
      data <- rbind.data.frame(data, b)
    }
```

The middle line is calling `length(data.frame$x)+1`, where `data.frame$x` is "obviously" not correct. I think you meant to use `data`, the frame you defined a few lines earlier. (It is referenced correctly in your three `changepoint` outputs.)

This is also the case on line 61.

The alternative of adding `browser()` to the beginning of each `observe`/`reactive` block would have brought you to the same conclusion.

Side-notes:

1. Naming a variable `data` could also produce the `'closure'` error, since if you do not define it then any operations on it will be dealing with the function `utils::data`. A lot of people name their stuff `data`, but that can be an obscure error (especially if you aren't aware of what a closure is).
2. Iteratively building a `data.frame` works in concept, but it scales poorly. Each time you add even just one row, it makes a complete copy in memory of all of the other rows. Doing this a few times is not bad, but it gets expensive later (and with larger data). See chapter 2, *Growing objects*, in the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). (For what you are doing here, it likely will not get *huge*, and there may be no easy way to work around it. Just keep it in mind.)
3. You do create `data`, but that instance is internal to the `observeEvent` and will not override the `data <- data.frame(...)` you defined just a few lines above it. While you *could* use a global assignment `<<-` to update the frame, all of your outputs that rely on that frame will not be reacting to its changes. When you have data that can change (and/or should be created manually) like this and should trigger reactive updates, then you should make it `reactive` data.

   I would change the middle section of your app to be something like:

   ```r
     mydata <- reactiveVal(data.frame(x = numeric(0), y = numeric(0)))

     observeEvent(input$button_click,{
       if (input$distribution == 'Normal'){
         set.seed(input$seed)
         a <- rnorm(input$length, input$mean, input$sd)
         b <- data.frame(x = seq(length(mydata()$x)+1, length(a)), y = a)
         mydata( rbind.data.frame(mydata(), b) )
       }
       if (input$distribution == 'Uniform'){
         set.seed(input$seed)
         a <- runif(input$length, input$min, input$max)
         b <- data.frame(x = seq(length(mydata()$x)+1, length(a)), y = a)
         mydata( rbind.data.frame(mydata(), b) )
       }
     })
   ```

   (Note that I renamed it to `mydata`, and because it is reactive data, you need to use `mydata()` to retrieve its value, and `mydata(newval)` to overwrite its value.)
4. I think your use of `seq(length(...)+1, length(a))` is slightly flawed. Note after you press the button once, your data will have 30 rows. Let's say you change `input$length` to 20 and press the button again, that call will be `seq(30+1, 20)`, which is not necessarily when you want. Perhaps `x = nrow(mydata()) + seq(input$length)`?

Comment: Funny ... so much of my code broke after troubleshooting this. It's funny how `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Latvian")` has so many side-effects to non-Latvian stuff. :-)